# Spring boot mapsId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I using spring boot jpa and I need to use mapsid. There are not so much information about that and I wonder if anyone can help me understand how to use maybe link a simple code example where its 2 table that joins 1 table (oneToOne)

Comment: Spring and Boot are irrelevant to `@MapsId`, they just configure the JPA provider. The documentation you're looking for will be about JPA rather than Spring.

Answer (score 0):

for a `@OneToOne` mapping, it  is  best to use  `@MapsId` .
There are certain benifits to this.
You can avoid using `@GeneratedValue` to your child class. This is more efficient as no separate Generation of Primary key is required.

You can use same key for finding same normalized data over `@OneToOne` relation.

For detailed explanation and reference, please visit [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) site. One of the best explanation out there.

Comment: It worked if I use  identify generedValue for Id

Comment: Yes certainly it works if you use GeneratedValue, `@MapsId` is a choice to use.
If you have been through the [link](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) I gave, you would be clear about the concept.